# Django Rest Framework обратные отношения

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Как вы выводите связанные объекты Django Rest Framework?

Есть две модели.

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    id         = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name       = models.CharField(max_length = 32, verbose_name = 'Имя')
    author     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Автор')
    status     = models.CharField(max_length = 32, choices = CHAT_STATUS, verbose_name = 'Статус')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'Дата создания')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, verbose_name = 'Дата редактирования')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Чат'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Чаты'

class Message(models.Model):
    id         = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    user       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Пользователь')
    chat       = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Чат')
    text       = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Текст')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'Дата создания')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, verbose_name = 'Дата редактирования')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Сообщение'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сообщения'
```

Мой serializer.

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = CutomUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'author', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

Моё представление выглядит так.

```
class ChatList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format = None):
        chat = Chat.objects.all()
        serializer = ChatSerializer(chat, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Как вывести все связанные объекты модели Message из ChatSerializer?

Comment: Вы как аргумент чата передаете в ChatSerializer? Из Ваших исходников это не очевидно.

Comment: Мне нужно получить все объекты модели Chat со связанными объектами модели Message.

Comment: У Вас же Message ссылается только на один чат, там ForeignKey... Какой тогда список Вы хотите получить?

Comment: По какому признаку Вы хотите найти эти Chat?

Comment: По id объекта модели Chat мне нужно получить объекты модели Message, если быть точным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Измени поле в models:**

> chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete = models.CASCADE,
>   verbose_name = 'Чат', related_name='messages')

добавь serializer для модели message:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Message
       fields = ['id', 'user', 'chat', text', 'created_at']


class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    author = CutomUserSerializer()   
    messages = MessageSerializer(many=True)



    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'author', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'messages']
```

*При подобном случае также стоит прибегнуть к оптимизации с помошью prefetch_related:*

```
class ChatList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format = None):
        chat = Chat.objects.all().prefetch_related('messages')
        serializer = ChatSerializer(chat, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось проще простого.

В модели для поля задал аргумент realted_name

```
chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'messages', verbose_name = 'Чат')
```

В serializer добавил.

```
messages = MessageSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)
```

Также в массив fields добавил поле messages.

```
fields = ['id', 'name', 'author', 'messages', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

Получил желаемый результат.